# iAd unavailable in GameScene.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, iad

I have imported iAd into my `GameScene.swift` file and for some reason I cannot call the `self.canDisplayBannerAds()` method. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Hummm, in what way can you not call that method? What error is it giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working code for you that just worked for me. This does not need `self.candisplaybannerads = true` as I had some issues with that. The ad automatically changes the size according to the screen size and is located at the bottom of the screen.

```
import iAd

class viewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var AdBanner = ADBannerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        /* Ad Banner Settings */

        AdBanner = ADBannerView()
        AdBanner.frame = CGRectZero
        AdBanner.delegate = self
        self.AdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-self.AdBanner.frame.size.height, self.AdBanner.frame.size.width, self.AdBanner.frame.size.height)
        AdBanner.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.view.addSubview(AdBanner)

}

/* All iAd Functions */

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
/* whatever you need */
    return true
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    AdBanner.hidden = false
}


func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("Error Loading Ad")
/* whatever you need */
    AdBanner.hidden = true
}
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}
```

Comment: This Worked! Thank you so much!   what can i do to remove it when I want to start the game again?

Comment: Nevermind! just removed it from superview! Thank you so much again!

Comment: No problem! Good luck on your app:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `canDisplayBannerAds` implement it like so:

```
import UIKit
import iAd // Import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showBanner()
    }

    func showBanner() {
        // Creates a self managed ADBannerView
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    }

    func hideBanner() {
        // Removes the ADBannerView
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = false
    }
```

Using `canDisplayBannerAds` creates and manages an `ADBannerView` for you. There's no need to implement additional methods and the `ADBannerView` will hide/show itself depending on if there is an advertisement available or not.

Answer (score -1):

Did you remember to inherrit from `ADBannerViewDelegate` AND `import iAd`

```
yourVC: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {
...
}
```